# Convert with imagemagick a multi layers psd into a merged layer tiff without visible modification

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I need to automatically convert PSD files with or without multiple layers into a TIFF LZW with only one layer, without noticeable differences.

Here is type of command I tried with Imagemagick 6.9.2-7 :

```
convert "fontaine_p7p.psd" -compress LZW -define tiff:endian=msb -background none -flatten fontaine_p7p.tif
```

Result is not as expected compare to the one obtained thanks to PhotoShop.
Layers are correctly merged, sizes of conversions are equivalent but I can see visible modifications on the Imagemagick tiff that are not visible on tiff generated thanks to PhotoShop.

Here are examples of a source PSD and the Tiff obtained via the imagemagick conversion above and where visible modifications are clearly iden : 
[PSD + TIFF + IdentifyVerbose](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByRmRqdU-OwbX090WXU3V2hqeVE/view?usp=sharing)

Here are details on PSD and TIFF files :

PSD :

```
identify fontaine_p7p.psd
fontaine_p7p.psd[0] PSD 782x819 782x819+0+0 8-bit CMYK 2.965MB 0.000u 0:00.000
fontaine_p7p.psd[1] PSD 544x819 544x819+226+0 8-bit CMYK 2.965MB 0.000u 0:00.000
fontaine_p7p.psd[2] PSD 335x819 335x819+447+0 8-bit CMYK 2.965MB 0.000u 0:00.000
fontaine_p7p.psd[3] PSD 782x13 782x13+0+806 8-bit CMYK 2.965MB 0.000u 0:00.000
fontaine_p7p.psd[4] PSD 782x819 782x819+0+0 8-bit CMYK 2.965MB 0.000u 0:00.000
fontaine_p7p.psd[5] PSD 782x819 782x819+0+0 8-bit CMYK 2.965MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

TIFF :

```
identify fontaine_p7p.tif
fontaine_p7p.tif TIFF 782x819 782x819+0+0 8-bit CMYK 1.552MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

It seems that imagemagick is not handling transparency is the same way as Photoshop during conversion to Tiff.

Is somebody have proposition to have a better result with such kind of procedure ? I already tried to replace the ("-flatten" option by "-layers merge" but in that case the transparency background is completely lost.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My guess is that it probably has something to do with ImageMagick not respecting the colour profile of the PSD file - and who can blame `IM` as Photoshop files are notoriously hard to reverse engineer... http://rebrn.com/re/scroll-down-and-read-this-comment-about-the-psd-file-format-753451/

Comment: Ok, good to know mark. 
Is somebody could at least tell me what is the differences between "-flatten et "-layer merge"? In my case, "-layer merge" give something really strange on transparencies...